# Which files in Wi-Fi diagnostics do I look at to troubleshoot an association issue, and/or 4 way handshake?

Tags: wifi, macos

I am troubleshooting some issues with my 5GHz SSID. The Wi-Fi module on my ISP modem crashes, knocking down all SSIDs, 2.4 and 5GHz. Both will reappear but devices cannot connect to the 5GHz, only 2.4. My tv error message says it's an authentication error but will fail after putting in the correct passphrase. If I reset the Wi-Fi module on the modem it will work, after putting in the passphrase.

What I am trying to do is identify the exact point where the process breaks by using the wifi diagnostics. I ran the diagnostics and unzipped the file and there is a ton of information.

Which files should I be concentrating on, without going on a needle/haystack search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think any of the files in there will help you debug such an issue.

Instead you could use a WiFi-sniffer in order to capture what's actually sent back and forth. However, be prepared to spend a lot of time on it - without any promise of actually being able to fix this yourself, as bugs in ISP modems are usually not fixable by customers.

I would consider buying a separate WiFi access point and disable WiFi in the ISP-supplied equipment.

Comment: This answers the core of my question, which was what files in diagnonstics to review. We did confirm there is a known firmware issue in that modem.